# MySQL combine result only if result exist in second table

Tags: mysql

I have one table with unique IDs and second table where these IDs have stored different values. Second table might have several rows with the ID from first table. I want to get print out complete content of table #one and have one more additional column containing only if one of ID matching ID from table one has * (star) character stored.

First Table

```
|id1|value1|value2|value3|value4|
```

Second table

```
|id2|value1|value2|id1|value4|
|   |      |      |   |     *|
```

Desired output

```
|id1|value1|value2|value3|value4|value5 with * or empty
```

What would be the mysql syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select *, s.value4
 from first_table f
 left outer join second_table s
   on f.id1 = s.id1
 and s.value4 = "*"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response. You were very helpfull!